# JS API login not working properly on IOS devices 7 safari browser

Tags: ios7, linkedin-jsapi

I am having this problem in Ipad Safari browser. It works fine on desktop safari, Chrome and Firefox.

On any example on developer.linkedinlabs.com/jsapi-console, when I click on "Signin with LinkedIn" button, it opens a new tab. This tab shows the title "Processing" and then hangs.

If I move to another tab and reactivate the "hanging" tab, it then works and brings up the linkedIn "login" window.

I have the same problem in my app.
Hoping someone can help how to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/15130#comment-15130) blog post, this is a problem that started on iOS 5: JavaScript code on background tabs gets paused.

So when you click on the "Sign in" and go to the second page, the first one has no way of bringing you back, since the code has paused.

I have tried to put the request in an iframe (to avoid this problem) by using the [place()](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inauth-inevent-and-inui) method on IN.UI, but had no success.

Can confirm this worked on older versions -- I tried it on an iPod Touch running iOS 4 and it works perfectly. :'(